# Google developer console is not working as expected when invited by other

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I get invitation from customer to join Google Developer account so that I can access details of project created in Google Developer Console. However recently, to get push worked using GCM key we have to import project into Firebase Console.

My question is, when I do import project into Firebase Console, it is getting imported into my Google account Firebase not the customer. Is that wrong? If yes, is there any way that we can ask customer to invite me to join their Firebase account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *when I do import project into Firebase Console, it is getting imported into my Google account Firebase not the customer. Is that wrong?*

If you are the owner of the Firebase project, then you are the only one that can import it to your own Firebase Console. so it is just expected. Others can't import a Google Project that they don't own to their own Firebase Console.

However, if added a specific account as a contributor, for this example a *Viewer*. If you imported the Project to your Firebase Console, they would also be able to see it in their own Firebase Console. See screenshot below:

[image]

Notice that there is a *View only* label on it. Since I only added the other account as a *Viewer*.